# Bootstrap 3 grids

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can somebody help me in removing the extra white space (column) on the rightmost part of my website. I have divided the row on wt-col-sm-3, wt-col-sm-6, wt-col-sm-3 columns but there's an extra white column wise space which I want to remove. I've tried a lot of options and changed css. But nothing seems to be working.

```html
<div id="slider_row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Module Megamenu-->
            <div id="wt-menu-ver-left" class="wt-menu-ver-left wt-col-sm-3 wt-col-md-2">
                <div class="title-menu-mobile category-title"><span>Category</span></div>
                 <div class="category-left" style="display: block;">
                    <ul class="menu-content">
                        <li class="level-1  parent">
                            <!-- All categories listings mobiles and accessories,tablets,laptops,Desktops &Monitors,Laptop Battery & charger -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /Module Megamenu --><!-- Module HomeSlider -->
            <div id="slider-wrapper" class="wt-col-md-6 wt-col-sm-6">
                <div id="layerslider" style="visibility: visible; width: 538px; height: 395.588px;" class="ls-container ls-v5">
                    <!--Mac book advertisement contents -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /Module HomeSlider --><!-- Static Block module -->
            <div id="slider-wrapper" class="wt-col-md-3 wt-col-sm-3">
                <p><img src="http://www.m.com/img/cms/freedel.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Free Delivery" width="200" height="174"></p>
                <p><img src="http://www.m.com/img/cms/GENUINE PR.png" class="img-responsive" alt="100% Genuine" width="200" height="144"></p>
                <p><img src="http://www.m.com/img/cms/pay1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Payment Methods" width="200" height="157"></p>
            </div>
            <!-- /Static block module -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For `medium` devices you have - `wt-col-md-2` + `wt-col-md-6` + `wt-col-md-3` which is 11, and bootstrap uses a 12 grid layout.

Comment: could you upload your front-end code in jsfiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. you did not distributed your columns in a proper way since you have `wt-col-md-2` + `wt-col-md-6` + `wt-col-md-3` for medium devices which gives 11 whereas bootstrap based on 12 grid layout system. Therefore you could try to do like this:

`wt-col-md-2` + `wt-col-md-7` + `wt-col-md-3`

or

`wt-col-md-2` + `wt-col-md-8` + `wt-col-md-2`

to fill whole width of a row.

B. I noticed that the width of your columns in wt-grid.scss file were calculated wrong, because two column layout, `wt-col-md-2` has width of 19.14529% and if you multiply it by 6 in order to get 12 column layout you will have a 114.87% instead of needed 100%. Moreover I did not find width for `wt-col-md-6` and `wt-col-md-7` classes, they were missing.

http://screencast.com/t/D9elhv9n

http://screencast.com/t/shwRKflSUq6

Good Luck!